# Control playback of the Spotify app from another Android app?

Tags: android, spotify

Is it possible to control playback of the Spotify app from within another Android app? I'm only looking for track skipping functionality (forward and backward).

I'm aware of the Spotify Android SDK, but it seems to only allow skipping of tracks played by the SDK:

```
com.spotify.sdk.android.playback.NativeSpotifyException: Failed SpPlaybackSkipToPrev with  error code 14 (The operation is not supported if the device is not the active playback device)
```

To clarify, both the actual Spotify app, and my own app are running on the same device

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Quick answer - No, this isn't possible.

Comment: I'll take this as the right answer coming from a Spotify employee

Comment: It probably wasn't back then, but at least now it is

Comment: @Auras, Are you able to skip tracks?

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to do it:

This will try to play/pause Spotify. If it's not running it will start it and make it start playing.

```
    public void nextSong() {

    int keyCode = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT;

    if (!isSpotifyRunning()) {
        startMusicPlayer();
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    intent.setPackage("com.spotify.music");
    synchronized (this) {
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyCode));
        getContext().sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keyCode));
        getContext().sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
    }
}

public void playPauseMusic() {
    int keyCode = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE;

    if (!mAudioManager.isMusicActive() && !isSpotifyRunning()) {
        startMusicPlayer();
    }

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    i.setPackage("com.spotify.music");
    synchronized (this) {
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyCode));
        getContext().sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);

        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keyCode));
        getContext().sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);
    }
}

private void startMusicPlayer() {
    Intent startPlayer = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startPlayer.setPackage("com.spotify.music");
    startPlayer.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getContext().startActivity(startPlayer);

    if (mMusicPlayerStartTimer != null) {
        mMusicPlayerStartTimer.cancel();
    }

    mMusicPlayerStartTimer = new Timer("MusicPlayerStartTimer", true);
    mMusicPlayerStartTimer.schedule(new MusicPlayerStartTimerTask(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS, DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
}

private boolean isSpotifyRunning() {
    Process ps = null;
    try {
        String[] cmd = {
                "sh",
                "-c",
                "ps | grep com.spotify.music"
        };

        ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        ps.waitFor();

        return ps.exitValue() == 0;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Could not execute ps", e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Could not execute ps", e);
    } finally {
        if (ps != null) {
            ps.destroy();
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private class MusicPlayerStartTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (isSpotifyRunning()) {
            playPauseMusic(null);
            cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added full example code

Comment: Are you able to skip tracks?

Comment: This actually still works. In the recent android versions it seems that you are no longer able to send commands just out there, but specifying the music player package (here com.spotify.music) actually works

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can control playback using the [RemoteController](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteController.html) classes, or if using Lollipop, the [MediaController](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController.html) classes, or if supporting L and earlier, then the [MediaControllerCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaControllerCompat.html) classes.

Then perform dispatchMediaButtonEvent() with [KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT).

Comment: Were you able to do this with Spotify? Seems like it won't work to me given than Spotify doesn't give you a MediaSessionCompat.Token

Comment: I'm doing it different by gaining Notification Listener permission