# Control MediaPlayer from personal app in background

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Have searched for solution but none has worked as i want.

Am developing a app for personal usage and want to control MediaPlayer from it, while application is in background. Is it possible and if so, how to achieve that ? Targeting Android 6.0+ and to control Spotify

Currently I'm only able to do that in a Rooted phone with exec command input keycode  but on unrooted phone this only works while app is in foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the best working example here:[Control Spotify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37418442/1071184)
Works great on A7.1.1
However when Spotify I brought to front, it's state is reset to home-screen.